# The real part of $zf''(z)/f'(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that $$\Re\ z\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}=r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\ln |f'(z)|, z\in D.$$
Here, $f$ is holomorphic in $D$, and $r=|z|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is a real operator (that means it commutes with conjugation, taking the real part etc.).

$\log \lvert f'(z)\rvert$ is the real part of $\log f'(z)$ [locally, there is not necessarily a global branch of $\log f'(z)$]. Then the chain rule gives

$$\begin{align}
r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \log f'(z) &= r \left(\frac{\partial \log f'(z)}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right)\tag{1}\\
&= r\left(\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}\cdot \frac{z}{r}\right)\\
&= z\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}.
\end{align}$$

There appears no $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\overline{z}}$ in $(1)$ since the function is holomorphic.

Take the real part to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Using chain rule and $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?

$f=u+iv$, $f'=...$,
${\partial\over\partial r}\ln|f'(r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta)|=...$